# Should I use identification numbers for usernames in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Right now I'm designing my MySQL database. Let's start with users table and comments table. What we see mostly is that the writer of the comment is stored as integer. However it requires to use left joins and when the application gets bigger you need few left joins in one query. Which at the end makes complicated queries. Can I make the users table without integers? And the writer of the comment will be stored with his username.

Also, there are `foreign keys` in MySQL. What practical advantages may I have if I use them?

Note: I use UTF-8 and the application (something like dictionary (first hand galactic encyclopedia)) is going to be in Cyrillic.

Comment: If you ever allow a user to change their username, this design will cause big headaches for you. Better to use an internal ID that is permanently associated with their account.

Comment: You can always create views to hide the joins from the application layer.

Answer (score 4):

you may.  but this will add processing overhead to any join - it is much faster to use numeric keys.

a couple of joins in a query is perfectly fine... MUCH better than denormalizing or making other data level changes for 'convenience'

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend using an integer as a key in your user table, set the field for auto-increment to guarantee uniqueness and so you don't have to set it yourself.  Then set a foreign key in your comments or other table.  The primary key field will be indexed and you are better off with this as an integer.  This concept is likely to be applied to many other places in your database design.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have really good reasons for not using surrogate keys then use them.

They make your life so much easier, because they are by definition a unqiue identifier for your entity which cannot change for the whole entity's life.

This is not true for natural primary keys like the username. Because they're natural they depend on appplication data. Constraints about application data that are valid today maybe invalid tommorow due to changes of functional requirements. Functional requirements are normally not under your control, because your customer dictates them. So normally it is not good to build your schema on constraints you cannot control yourself.

Therefore use surrogate keys except you've good reasons for not using them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its uneasy to tell for sure, which option is better, as it depends on many factors (will a user be able to change his username? will you allow unregistered users to post comments? etc.)

Please consider a solution, where in `comments` table you store BOTH username and numeric userid. This way you denormalize data, but can have some performance benefits (you actually store username as it was at the moment of placing a comment so it is not denormalization actually - to be strict. :]).

Comment: If a user ever changes their username, this will require an `UPDATE` on all tables that reference the user table... far from ideal.

Comment: Well, if you want the "cached username" to be correct, then yes, you would.

Comment: No if you assume, that you want comment by "cdhowie" to be always displayed with "cdhowie" alongside even after "cdhowie" changes his username to "frank". which username is correct is a question of a business rule - not a database design.

Comment: I cannot advocate storing the username alongside a foreign-key user id, unless that is the requirement -- that old data be displayed with old usernames.  If the requirement is that old data be displayed with current usernames (which is almost always the case), then this approach would be foolish.

Comment: Even if, calling it foolish is rather rude. OP was wondering about performance and denormalization is always about performance. You perform thousands of queries that display comments with usernames, and how often does one change his/her username?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14479/discussion-between-cdhowie-and-kuba-wyrostek)